# Quotation marks in Camel Content-Type header

Tags: java, soap, https, apache-camel, content-type

I am trying to invoke a SOAP service using camel-http4. This service requires me to send the following header: Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="ListBerichten". I have to include the quotation marks, or otherwise the service will return a 400 code

When I try this with a client like Postman or SoapUI or curl  it works fine, but when I try it with Camel, it fails to recognize the 'action'.

(the curl header looks like this)
`--header 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="ListBerichten"'`

I suspect it has something to do with the quotation marks around ListBerichten, but I can't figure out what it is.

My Camel Route (I'm using a custom http4 implementation for SSL configuration):

```
        from("direct:d.receive.{{name}}.listberichten").routeId("ReceiveListBerichten")
                .to("xslt:file:{{xslt.cdm.to.target.listberichten}}?saxon=true")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD).simple("POST")
                .setHeader("Content-Type").simple("{{soap.contentType.listberichten}}")
                .to("mTlsHttpComponent://{{request.url}}/{{request.url.path}}?useSystemProperties=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=true").id("Receive3")
        ;
```

and my properties

```
xslt.cdm.to.target.listberichten=\/data\/resources\/...
soap.contentType.listberichten=application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="ListBerichten"

request.url=...
request.url.path=...

logging.show.info=showAll=true
```

And the response I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <soap:Code>
                <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
            </soap:Code>
            <soap:Reason>
                <soap:Text xml:lang="nl">Err: Unknown SOAPAction:</soap:Text>
            </soap:Reason>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've tried escaping the quotes with backslashes, replacing the quotes with UTF-8 encoded characters, setting the header as a String literal and setting the 'action' in a separate header but nothing seems to work. How do I need to deal with the quotation marks in the Content-Type header?

Comment: `application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="ListBerichten"` is a valid value inside a properties file and doesn't need escaping. camel-http4 is probably using a `Properties` class to read the file so it should pose no issue. Are you sure the quotation marks are the problem? Maybe something else is amiss. Since you are already using SoapUI, try to send your request through its HTTP Monitor and look at what's being sent on the wire: https://www.soapui.org/docs/http-recording/reference/http-monitor/

Comment: In general, the soap action is passed as a **separate** http header named "SOAPAction" rather than in the "Content-Type" header. Ok it does not explain why it works with curl, but this could be a workaround.

Comment: @TacheDeChoco: the namespace in the SOAP fault above is one for SOAP 1.2 which requires the action to be on the content type. A SOAPAction separate header is for SOAP 1.1.

Comment: It could be useful to try first with an hard-coded header:  `.setHeader("Content-Type").constant("application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=\"ListBerichten\"")` in order to understand the root cause

Comment: @Bogdan hanks for your help. I intercepted the HTTP traffic, but this gave the same header. So I started digging in the http4 component, and I found that it uses org.apache.http.message.TokenParser, which removes the quotes from the soap action, before making the http request. I switched to the camel-netty-http4 component and this worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action parameter is the default way to set the SOAP Action in SOAP version 1.2. The HTTP component parses the content-type values however. Alternative you can use:

1. [netty-http](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/netty-http-component.html) component (since Camel 2.14)
2. [vertx-http](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/vertx-http-component.html) component (since Camel 3.5)

Both components don't parse the header values.